# MySQL Sorting number issue

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have few number sets that I'm trying to word

```
4.13.1.5, 4.13.1, 4.10.5, 4.9.97
```

But when I use mysql order by function somehow it sorts out in an odd way.

```
4.13.1.5, 4.13.1, 4.9.37, 4.10.5
```

Should it be that 4.9 comes at the end? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you please post your query?

Comment: Those aren't the same (the first has `4.9.97` and the second has `4.9.37`).  Could you post the exact strings you're talking about?

Comment: There is no `4.9` in your data. There is `4.9.37` and that should go to the front or to the end depending on whether `.` sorts before or after the digits. Please tell us how the query looks like and what data type you use for the "numbers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are technically strings and not numbers, MySQL is doing the correct thing. The `.` (character 46) is higher in sort order than any of the numbers (characters 48-59). When it comes to comparing the string, it's going by ASCII value not breaking it down in to tokens and comparing the numbers.

Comment: That doesn't make sense since all the "numbers" have the same leading first 2 characters.  So it should sort on the third+ (1, 1, 9, 1 from the result order).  So it really doesn't make sense why the 9 would be in the 2nd position...  (Unless I miss-read)...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
mysql> create table test ( value varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)


mysql> insert into test values ("4.13.1.5"), ("4.13.1"), ("4.10.5"), ("4.9.97")
    -> ;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select value from test order by value;
+----------+
| value    |
+----------+
| 4.10.5   |
| 4.13.1   |
| 4.13.1.5 |
| 4.9.97   |
+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why does 4.10 come all the way on top? Shouldn't 4.13 come at the top

Comment: The comparison is not numeric (those are strings, and 0 comes before 3).